# Importing KML Data into Google Collab

Tags: kml

I'm attempting to read an hourly precipitation KML file from https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/metadata/geoportal/rest/metadata/item/gov.noaa.ncdc:C00313/html
in Google Collab but I am coming up short on finding libraries accessible in Collab for reading KML files. Does anyone have experience or insight into whether or not this is possible and how to do it if it is?

Comment: Is this Earth Engine related?

Comment: This is earth engine related in that I will be comparing data gathered with earth engine to the kml precipitation data